# About Intel's strip mining example

Tags: c++, performance, for-loop, cpu-cache

In Intel's strip mining example:

https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/strip-mining-to-optimize-memory-use-on-32-bit-intel-architecture

Why not merge Transform and Lighting into one loop? It would solve the cache eviction problem.

Someone has asked the same question in the comments but there is no answer.

If splitting the loop is somehow faster ... Why? Under what conditions should we split loops?

I looked through several posts about splitting loops but I still don't get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If only one of those operations can be vectorized, then combining them could prevent vectorization of the loop. In that case dividing the array into cache sized stripes would be better. I don't know if that applies to `Transform` and `Lighting`. If not, then maybe they aren't necessarily a good example for the demonstration.

When the loop is partially vectorizable (is that a word?) and partly not, fission* is usually the way to go.

*splitting is actually the name for the technique used in the article according to the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_optimization)